# Webpack multiple proxies not working - getting 404 error

Tags: webpack-dev-server

I am trying to set up multiple proxies in my project. I have two projects locally. In one of them I need to fetch data from two remote backends of this two projects. I have set up the webpack file like this:

```
var options = {
  contentBase: "src/client",
  proxy: {
    "fpHandling/api/**": {
      target: "http://localhost:8030",
      secure: false,
    },
    "fpCase/api/**": {
        target: "http://localhost:8080",
        secure: false,
    },
  },
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  noInfo: true,
  historyApiFallback: false,
  stats: {
    colors: true,
  },
};

var wds = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), options);

wds.listen(9999, 'localhost', function(err) {
  if (err) {
      return console.log(err); //NOSONAR
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:9999/');
});
```

But, I can't get the data from the remote backend `fpCase/api/` , I get `404` error. But, the same endpoint works in the other project where I only have a single proxy that is set up like this:

```
proxy: {
    "**/api/**": {
      target: "http://localhost:8080",
      secure: false,
    },
  },
var wds = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), options);

wds.listen(9000, 'localhost', function(err) {
  if (err) {
      return console.log(err); 
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:9000/');
});
```

In the console I can see that the request is sent to the port that is

```
Request URL: http://localhost:9999/fpCase/api/
```

I guess the problem is in the ports, since the port of the server on which the project is running is `9999` and the port of the target is `8080`. In the other project that can reach this endpoint the port is set to `9000` and there it works.
What am I doing wrong, how should I set up multiple proxies so that I can fetch data from both backends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, then the solution should be to "rewrite requests" to your proxy by using the `pathRewrite` parameter on a per-proxy basis.

So for instance, if you app issues a request to a route at `/fpHandling/api/*` then you'd want that request to be relayed to the equivalent of `http://localhost:9999/*`.

To achieve this, you can update your options configuration like so:

```
var options = {
  contentBase: "src/client",
   proxy: {

       "/fpHandling/api/*": {
           target: "http://localhost:9999",
           secure: false,
           pathRewrite: { '^/fpHandling/api': '' }
       },

       "/fpHandling/spark/*": {
           target: "http://localhost:9999",
           secure: false,
           pathRewrite: { '^/fpHandling/spark': '' }
        },

        "/fpCase/api/*": {
           target: "http://localhost:8888",
           secure: false,
           pathRewrite: { '^/fpCase/api': '' }
        }
  },
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  noInfo: true,
  historyApiFallback: false,
  stats: {
    colors: true,
  },
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same 404 error even with the prefix.

Comment: Interesting - I think I noticed another subtly that might be causing you problems. Does the updated answer help?